# change input value before submit form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to set hidden input value(username) based on client other input(email) in a form, then submit to server. (to make sure username equal to email)

However, the assignment to the hidden input is processed *AFTER* the form submitted. So 'username' is already None on server side.

```
<form id="altForm" action="" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="username" id="id_username" maxlength="40" >

<input type="email" name="email" id="id_email" maxlength="40">

<input class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

---

```
<script>

    $("#altForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var username = $("#id_email").val();
        $("#id_username").val(username);

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Why; if the values are the same in each do you really need the hidden input?

Comment: I may set hidden input value 'username' based on the value 'email'. For example, username='example' if email='example@somesite.com'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this serverside, but if you want it clientside you can also accomplish it like this:

```
$('#id_email').keyup(function() {
    $('#id_username').val($(this).val());
});
```